# Ant flaka Is jar not updated?

Tags: ant, flaka

I tried to use [flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/), but i always get an error that says that the class PropertyHelper12 isn't found. I looked in the jar file and actually there isn't that file, but it's available in the source code.

**Does anyone know if there is a well made jar file for flaka? I mean updated with sources?**

Thanks!

*PS: I tried to tag this question with flaka, but i can't because i have < 1500 rep.. :/*

Comment: Why don't you try making the jar out of source code that contains this class file?

Comment: Yeah. i just tried. It seems there was an error with build

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was due to the build available in the website. If some one wants to get flaka i suggest to:

- Download the trunk source code, using `svn checkout http://flaka.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ flaka-read-only`
- cd to the source directory and run `ant` to build the source
- cd to dist and the right jar file is `ant-flaka.*.jar`

Answer (score 0):

U p d a t e

***Flaka Version 1.02.01 has been released*** incl. updated jar, sources and development package, get it on [Flaka Download Site](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/downloads/list) !

---

The problem lies within the build script build.xml.
If build runs with ant version < 1.8.0 the PropertyHelper12 Class gets excluded from the jar.

see build.xml, line 292 :

```
<exclude name="**/*PropertyHelper12*" unless="ant-gte-180" />
```

The flaka download will be fixed soon !!

Until that you may grep the sources and build with ***Ant 1.8.x*** to get the
PropertyHelper12 Class included and all will work as expected